# Ubuntu 22.04 automatically boots in the middle of the night HP EliteDesk

Tags: boot

I simply cannot find why my one HP Elite Desk boots up on its own in the middle of the night. I've searched "auto boot" and all I get is auto run info. Any thoughts would be very helpful.

[The Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2nQW.png)

Comment: This does not seem to be Ubuntu related. Is this system connected to Ethernet LAN? You may have to disable Wake-on-LAN.

Comment: Thank you, I don't remember enabling Wake-on-LAN during the install and I have three other same desktops with the same OS in service and they don't behave this way. Curious, I'll check the BIOS of that machine.

Comment: It wasn't Wake-on-LAN it was a setting in the bios. Unfortunately I don't remember what the setting was except it was under the boot options under the advanced tab.